# CImage::Save caused error Thread 0x**** has exited with code 1 (0x1)

Tags: multithreading, mfc

I'm working on a small app on Windows.

It uses `CImage` to write a PNG file on disk.

It just goes like this:

```
CImage theImage;
...
theImage.Save("D:\\xxx.png");
```

After the file was written on the disk and I clicked the close button on the top-right corner to exit the program. The console showed me a message like this:

```
Thread 0x**** has exited with code 1 (0x1)
Program "[*****] xxx.exe" has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Code 0x1 should indicate an error, right? Seems something wrong happened when the thread created by `CImage::Save` was writing the file.

The image file is perfectly on the disk, nothing wrong with it. And I checked the return value of `Save`, it also indicated success.

I have walked through all my code and I'm sure it is definitely caused by the invocation of `CImage::Save`, if I don't call it, this message never pops up. That is, the console would look like this:

```
Program "[*****] xxx.exe" has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I did some search and I found [this post](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?354017-The-thread-Win32-Thread-(0x5a4)-has-exited-with-code-1-(0x1)), but they didn't work it out either.

Even though the program didn't crash, but this message still annoys me.

Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Based on what specification do you assume that a return value of 1 from an arbitrary thread indicates an error?

Answer (score 0):

"Code 0x1 should indicate an error, right?"

Only in the most abstract meaning of 'error'. Whoever authored the creation and destruction of the thread decided what value to return, and what that value meant. Could be that someone used some library that required cleanup which didn't get done in time, or another of 1000 possible causes. Not something to spend time on.

Comment: All right, (although without any proof) I just thought that the thread was created by the framework as a worker thread to write the file on the disk, so it should exit with a return code 0x0 if the work was done properly and should exit long before I close the program rather than wait until the moment I click the close button. Anyway, like you said, not something to spend time on, since I don't know anything about what that  thread is for and what the exit code 0x1 means. :-)